# client/server php web application with many databases

Tags: php, networking, web-applications, client-server

we developed a PHP web application for a company, they want to install it on the server and let their departments access it, but every department should have its own database for the same web application.
So how can we do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest method I can suggest for the given context is:

1. Create multiple file with configuration of different department. The structure would look like

`-root
  -include
    -db
      -dept_sales.conf.php
      -dept_support.conf.php`

2. I assume your application would have a login where user can login into the system.
   Pass the dept as a parameter in the URL. 
   Create your url as below:

`http://example.com/login.php?dept=sales
 http://example.com/login.php?dept=support`

3. Depending the value of `dept` include the respective configuration file and store it in session, so that you don't have to do this for every URL.

Other alternative for Point 2 could be that give a dropdown on the homepage asking which department the user belong and load the respective conf file.